# Jquery Mobile Collapsible Content Font Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I need to change the font size of several, but not all, items in a JQuery Collapsible  but cannot seem to get it to work.  Does anyone have some advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out.  It works if I apply the style to the span element but not the div.  I should have tried that before I posted my question.